# Mint leaves are weak and have black spots/yellowish

Tags: mint

Recently i started noticing my mint leaves are turning yellow,weak and sometimes have black spots.

I tried using the DIY pesticide /fungicide (baking soda,soap,oil,water ) but it's not really helping.[image]

also got rid of the infected leaves but it doesnt seem to help.

does anybody know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Does  the pot have drainage holes and how long has  the mint been in the same pot?

Comment: It does have drainage ,i also put tuff rocks at the bottom.
it's been here  for about 3 months probably.